# Passive voice for sentences using modals and "used to:

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

I always have some problems with changing an active sentence which contains *used to* into a passive sentence, for example:

> Mr Green used to teach languages at school.

What is the passive form? Is it

> Languages were used to be taught at school.

or is it

> Languages used to be taught at school.

Answer (score 3):

You could begin by replacing the "used to" by "once" or "formerly" so your active sentence (past tense) becomes

> Mr Green once taught languages at school.

The passive form will then be

> Languages were once taught at school by Mr Green.

Note it would be more usual to be more specific about where the languages were taught (since languages now forms the focus of the sentence.

> Languages were once taught at this school by Mr Green.

If you really want to retain the "used to" form, then you can replace "were once" with "used to be" giving

> Languages used to be taught at this school by Mr Green.

Answer (score 1):

The correct passive sentence on a formal English test would be neither of yours. It would be this:

> Languages used to be taught at school **by Mr Green**.

Comment: Really? That's stupid. 90% of natural passives are agentless. One of the big reasons to use the passive is because the agent is unknown or irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnL: Yes, of course, but formal English tests are frequently stupid, especially in countries where EFL's required. If an EFL/ESL teacher wants an agentless passive, then perhaps asking students to passivize _School used to have language classes_ would be better; perhaps not. _Languages used to be taught at school_ is natural for me. _Some faculty used to teach languages at school_ invites an agentless passive, but _Mr Green used to teach languages at school_ makes Mr Green important. Deleting the agent changes the topic & the nature of the discourse. Maybe I'm thinking in Japanese.

Comment: No, same in English, but we don't use the same marking system.

Comment: JL is requiring an answer to 'What is the usual passive form associated with ...' whereas BF is requiring an answer to 'What is a semantically very close passive recast of ...'.

Comment: @Edwin: Yes. My experience with EFL students from all over the world is that their non-native EFL teachers generally demand close semantic equivalents & accept very, very few idiomatically correct English equivalents of what they want as answers. The tests aren't made by pro testmakers who understand how to test real usage, just English as algebra. Who qualifies as a testmaker? Just any old English teacher. I studied how to make good tests, but I never learned how to do it for EFL. I don't think it's possible on paper. Maybe the test is only _Do I understand what you mean?_

Comment: But all tests here & in other countries are _Fill in the blanks_, _Turn S1 into a passive_, _Turn S2 into an active_, _Translate S1 into English & S2 into Chinese_. On paper. My only tests are _Did you say what you mean & mean what you said?_, _Did I understand what you said/wrote?_, & _Does my revised sentence say what you want it to say?_ JL & I agree on the purpose of the passive: unknown or irrelevant agent.

Comment: Plus, I suspect, we agree that we have no reason whatever to cooperate with such a silly and counterproductive system. I'm certainly not here to improve anyone's curriculum; I think curricula are evil.

Comment: @JohnL: Yes, we agree on that, too. My goal was to teach EFL students how to actually use the language so they could clearly express themselves & be easily understood. I created all my own materials based on what my students needed, avoided useless forays into the grammar-book jungle, & gave no written tests.

Comment: Pretty much my own experience when I taught ESL for 6 years, during and after my MA studies. This taught me how little I knew about English syntax; when I went back to get my PhD I made sure I concentrated on that. ESL and Native students are all blinkered by ridiculous grammar books, test, and teachers. But they're different for ESL and Native learners.

Comment: @JohnL: In Taiwan & Japan, everything is prescribed by the Ministry of Education bureaucrats, & teachers must fall into line. All evaluations are quantitative: No student-number left behind & no teacher-number goes unnoticed. What's good for General Bullmoose is good for the education business.