# Usage 'used to' in Passive Sentence

Tags: passive-voice, used-to

Is below the sentence correct?

**Information:**

Mean of 'used to' shouldn't be 'past habits'. It should be passive sentence.

**Sentence:**

> This table used to define batch.

I want to say : I use the table for defining batch.

Comment: For a phrasing or a quotation, a native speaker would use "I want to say" instead of "I want to tell."

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112849/passive-voice-for-sentences-using-modals-and-used-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into an English idiom.  "**Used to X**" means that X happened in the past and no longer does:

> I **used to run** five miles a day, but I don't any more.

For what you want, use (if you'll forgive the word) the **passive voice**:

> This table **is used** to define batch.

Notice the presence of a form of the verb "to be" (here, "was") to form the passive.

Comment: The idiom *used to* as in *When I lived in Hong Kong I used to play Mahjong in the evenings* is a progressive past, and is rendered in French with the imperfect. So they have no way of distinguishing *I used to play...* from *I was playing...*. English is a language with great facility.